# How do I connect Visual studio 2013 to TFS 2018 server

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

How do I connect Visual studio 2013 to TFS 2018 server?

I have tried installing an old dap for vs 2010, without much luck.

My server is TFS 2018 u2, desktop has VS 2013 and VS 2015. I can connect with VS 2015, but not with VS 2013.

What do I need to install to get this to work?

Comment: What do you mean you can not connect with 2013? when you try to connect to the server in the team explorer did you get an error message?

Comment: Does this compatibility table help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/compatibility?view=vsts

Comment: I am getting TFS31002: Unable to connect to Team Foundation Server:xxxx Team Foundation Server Url: xxxx. Possible reasons. ...

Answer (score 1):

You may need to install (or repair) your `VS 2013`/`Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2013` in the following order:

- Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2013 (requires MSDN subscription)
- Visual Studio 2013 update 5 (requires MSDN subscription)

More information please refer to [Connect any version of Visual Studio to Visual Studio Team Services or Team Foundation Server](https://jessehouwing.net/vsts-tfs-connect-any-visual-studio-version/#te2013).

Comment: I upgraded VS 2013 to update 5 and tried to connect again, I got following error . "TFS31002: Unable to connect to Team Foundation Server:xxxx Team Foundation Server Url: xxxx. Possible reasons. ..."

Comment: I can connect to the same TFS 2018 server using VS 2015.

Comment: Also  I can connect to TFS 2013 using VS 2013. Another point is, My VS 2013 is community edition and VS 2015 is Enterprise edition. Not sure if that makes difference

Comment: @Nate Have you repaired the Team Explorer for VS 2013? What's the Possible reasons? Could you share the details message for troubleshoot? Whatever, you can refer to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms244143%28v=vs.80%29?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to check the scenarios and troubleshoot accordingly.

Comment: This is the complete error: "TFS31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server https://xxx.xx.xxx:8080/tfs. Team foundation server url: https://xxx.xx.xxx:8080/tfs.  Possible reasons for failure include: - The name, port number, or protocol for the team foundation server is incorrect. - The team foundation server is offline. - The Password has expired or is incorrect. Technical information (for administrator): The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

Comment: Above is the full error message, I did make sure that the values are correct, the login has valid permissions and tried to use the same settings on VS 2015 and it can connect to TFS 2018 u2.

Comment: Didn't have much luck with ip address. I get the same error with TF31002 code.

Comment: @Nate Can you reproduce this issue on other client machines? Tested on my side with the VS 2013 community edition, everything works as expected. Suggest you clean the caches on your client machine,then try it again. Reference https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsalm/2013/12/17/how-to-clear-the-tfs-cache-on-client-machines/